# cordova3.6.3 app not works in ipad5.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, cordova

I develop an appllication using cordova3.6.3 in xcode5.1.1,
when i test the appliction in emulator everything working, but while device testing when i open appliction by clicking app iocn its not works(app not open).
i am using ipad5.1.1 version.

after run the application, i am getting threads in HelloCordova.app file like
dyld_fatal_error
libdyld.dylib`dyld_stub_binder
in console i am getting errors

2014-11-03 10:59:45.828 HelloCordova[3228:707] CRITICAL: For Cordova 3.5.0 and above, you will need to upgrade to at least iOS 6.0 or greater. Your current version of iOS is 5.1.1.
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _objc_setProperty_nonatomic_copy

Comment: what are Base SDK & iOS Deployment Target of your App?

Comment: Base SDK is: Latest ios(ios 7.1)

Comment: Base SDK Latest ios(ios 7.1) and deployment target is 5.0 when i change base sdk to ios5.0 and Deployment target to 7.0 devices not shown in active scheme

Comment: have u tried with minimum deployment target? base sdk will be latest ios

Comment: i had tried to set minimum base sdk,but not working getting errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS 5 support was removed on cordova 3.5, so you have to use cordova 3.4 or earlier if you want to support iOS 5

cordova 3.5 release notes
http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2014/05/23/cordova-350.html

More info
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4863